# How can I do a JOIN with Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

How can I do a `Join` with another `Entity` ?

I have this one,

`IEnumerable<EntityNetimoveis.San_Imovel> im = db.San_Imovel.Where(a => a.Credenciada_Id.Equals(10));`

I want a `JOIN` with `San_Imovel_Caracteristica`. Primary Key and Foreign Key called `Imovel_Id`

I try this one

`IEnumerable<EntityNetimoveis.San_Imovel> im = db.San_Imovel.Join.(IEnumerable<EntityNetimoveis.San_Imovel_Caracteristica>, i => imovel_id, a => imovel_Id).Where(a => a.Credenciada_Id.Equals(10));`

but this is a wrong code. Has syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, joining is like this.

```
var im = 
db.San_Imovel.Join(db.San_Imovel_Caracteristica, i => i.imovel_id, a => a.imovel_Id, (i, a) => a)
.Where(a => a.Credenciada_Id.Equals(10));
```

Edited:

For example,

```
var result = db.ATable
.Where(a => a.Name == 'test')
.Join(db.BTable, a => a.Id, b => b.Id, (a, b) => a);
```

Comment: I think we are closest of a solution. But I got a error in this solution that you develop. `The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Join<> cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicity.`

Comment: What is this `(i, a) => a`  ?

Comment: Are you comparing same types? For example, both i.imovel_id and a.imovel_id must be interger values.

Comment: (i, a) => a means select San_Imovel_Caracteristica table. If you change it to (i, a) => i, it will return San_Imovel table.

Comment: I added the example, so you can get the clear idea about the syntax. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5038416/296861

Answer (score 0):

There's a "." after Join that shouldn't be there

Comment: uhh, but that won't fix it :P

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from EntityNetimoveis.San_Imovel i in db.San_Imovel
    join EntityNetimoveis.San_Imovel_Caracteristica c in db.San_Imovel_Caracteristica on i.imovel_id equals c.imovel_Id
    select i;

return query.ToList();
```

Comment: I need something closest the logic that I'm using. With lambda expressions