# EF 6 select from other table without navigation property

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a small problem which I need a help to solve:

I have following situation:

For example: I want to select all students who have a dog.

I have 2 tables:

```
students 
id name petid

pet
id name
```

BUT there is no specified foreign key between them no navigation property, although I have but I haven't specified it and I don't want for my case, but I still want to make a correct select statement.

So with navigation property i could query like this:

```
var students = (student s in context.students where s.Pet.Name.Equals("dog").ToList();
```

I would avoid doing this also

```
var students = context.students

foreach(student s in students)
{
    string pet = (from pet p in context.pets where p.Id==s.PetId select p.name).SingleOrDefault();
     if(pet=="dog")
     { 
         //do something
     } 
}
```

Of course it would be easy to make navigation property, but for my case I really don't want to.

So my question is how can i do this kind of query simple and with only one to DB?

Comment: To make navigation property is not so easy, if someone need it,  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465855/entity-framework-add-navigation-property-manually/21455438#21455438

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a join.

```
var students = (from s in context.students
  join p in context.pets on s.petid equals p.id
  where p.name == "dog"
  select s).ToList();
```

For the lambda syntax, you can use this:

```
var students = context.students.Join(context.pets.Where(p => p.name== "dog"), //filter the pets
                             student => student.PetId, //left side key for the join
                             pet => pet.id, //right side key for the join
                             (student, pet) => student); //what do you want to select
```

Comment: I will test it, but just curious what if i use this type of writing query: context.studnets.Where().Where().Select() ... how to use join here? context.students.Where().Join(...) how do i write the join in lambda here?

Comment: Here is an example to do it with Lamda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038288/lambda-expression-for-join

Comment: I have never liked the Lambda syntax for the join. It's not nearly as readable, IMHO.